# How do I change an assigned material

Tags: materials

I have created a 'model' (sorry can't remember the correct term) using an existing blender file and rearranging the meshes which already had a image texture material assigned to each mesh. I want to use a different image texture material but cannot remove the existing assigned material from a single mesh. I have attached the blender file and I want to replace the assigned materials for each mesh FROM 'material.concrete.tiles.rotated.001' TO 'concrete.tiles.rotated.2.tone'.
Firstly I need to know how to create a blender file 30Mb or less. The file was 46Mb in size so I selected at least half of the 'model'/object and hit the delete key which removed that half from the screen and then saved but the resulting file is still 46Mb which doesn't make sense.
Until U can upload the blender file you will have no idea what my problem is.

[image]

Comment: To change the material of some faces, switch to Edit mode, select the unwanted material in the material list, click on Select button, which will select all the faces that have the material, select the new material in the list, click on Assign

Comment: Wonderful and thanks. I have never had this problem and what could have caused it?

Comment: I can't say, it's not clear what happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the material of some faces, switch to *Edit* mode, select the unwanted material in the material list, click on the *Select* button, which will select all the faces that have the material, select the new material in the list, and click on the *Assign* button.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *Remap Users* feature.

In the outliner expand your object until the materials list appear. Right click on the material you want to change for another one, and select *Remaps Users*. In the dropdown menu, select the name of your wanted material.

[image]

Note that :

- The previous material will have its users set to 0, this means that it will be removed from the file once you save & reload it. If you want to keep the material, you need to set it to *Fake User*.
- This will remap *all* occurrences of your material by the new one across your file, this may or may not be what you want.
- If you have a *lot* of materials in your file, the list can get extremely long and hard to visually parse. This is a known limitation of this feature.